# Directx exception

Tags: c++, directx

I have a project that I started a while ago on my other laptop, which was running windows vista. I got a new laptop running windows 8, and wanted to run the project on it, but it gives me an unhandled exception. I have directx included in the program. It says Unhandled exception at 0x0f91a253. violation reading location 0xae8b587c. Here is some of my code

```
#pragma region Effects
    // Load our effect file 

    D3DXCreateEffectFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Effect.fx", 0, 0, 0, 0, &m_pEffect, &m_pEffectError);

    m_hTech = m_pEffect->GetTechniqueByName("Effect");

    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//Sun.jpg", &m_pTexture[0]);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//earth.jpg", &m_pTexture[1]);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//mercury.jpg", &m_pTexture[2]);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//venus.jpg", &m_pTexture[3]);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//mars.jpg", &m_pTexture[4]);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//jupiter.jpg", &m_pTexture[5]);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//saturn.jpg", &m_pTexture[6]);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//uranus.jpg", &m_pTexture[7]);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//neptune.jpg", &m_pTexture[8]);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"1.bmp", &mTex0);
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"Textures//moon.jpg", &m_pTexture[9]);

    m_pEffect->SetTexture("Texture", mTex0);
    m_pEffect->SetFloat("DiffuseIntensity", 1.5f );
    m_pEffect->SetFloat("LineThickness", 0.15f );

#pragma endregion Effects

#pragma region Object Positions
    //positions

    DirectInput8Create(hInst, DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, IID_IDirectInput8, (void**)&input, NULL);

    // Initialize Keyboard
    input->CreateDevice(GUID_SysKeyboard, &m_pDIKeyboard, NULL);

    // Initialize Mouse
    input->CreateDevice(GUID_SysMouse, &m_pDIMouse, NULL);

    // Set up Keyboard
    m_pDIKeyboard->SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, DISCL_FOREGROUND | DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE);
    m_pDIKeyboard->SetDataFormat(&c_dfDIKeyboard);

    // Set up Mouse (c_dfDIMouse2 = 8 button mouse)
    m_pDIMouse->SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, DISCL_FOREGROUND | DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE);
    m_pDIMouse->SetDataFormat(&c_dfDIMouse2);



    D3DXVECTOR3 pos[12];

    planetscaling[0] = 95.0f;
    planetscaling[1] = 900.0f;
    planetscaling[2] = 900.0f;
    planetscaling[3] = 900.0f;
    planetscaling[4] = 1000.0f;
    planetscaling[5] = 600.0f;
    planetscaling[6] = 650.0f;
    planetscaling[7] = 665.0f;
    planetscaling[8] = 660.0f;
    planetscaling[9] = 1350.0f;

    pos[0] = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, planetscaling[0]);         // Sun
    pos[1] = D3DXVECTOR3(150.0f, 20.0f, planetscaling[1]);      // Earth
    pos[2] = D3DXVECTOR3(50.0f, 50.0f, planetscaling[2]);       // Mercury
    pos[3] = D3DXVECTOR3(100.0f, 0.0f, planetscaling[3]);       // Venus
    pos[4] = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -200.0f, planetscaling[4]);      // Mars
    pos[5] = D3DXVECTOR3(-40.0f, 0.0f, planetscaling[5]);       // Jupiter
    pos[6] = D3DXVECTOR3(-50.0f, -100.0f, planetscaling[6]);    // Saturn
    pos[7] = D3DXVECTOR3(20.0f, -100.0f, planetscaling[7]);     // Uranus
    pos[8] = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -70.0f, planetscaling[8]);       // Neptune
    pos[9] = D3DXVECTOR3(300.0f, 320.0f, planetscaling[9]); 

    Object[0].set(Sun,    pos[0], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // Sun
    Object[1].set(PLANET, pos[1], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // Earth
    Object[2].set(PLANET, pos[2], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // Mercury
    Object[3].set(PLANET, pos[3], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // Venus
    Object[4].set(PLANET, pos[4], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // Mars
    Object[5].set(PLANET, pos[5], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // Jupiter
    Object[6].set(PLANET, pos[6], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // Saturn
    Object[7].set(PLANET, pos[7], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // Uranus
    Object[8].set(PLANET, pos[8], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // Neptune
    Object[9].set(MOON,   pos[9], 4.8f, -1, mTex0); // moon

#pragma endregion Object Positions

}
void PlanetClass::Update(double dt, IDirect3DDevice9*   m_pD3DDevice)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            continue;
        D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rotMat, (float)timeGetTime() * 0.009f);
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&TransMat, Object[i].position.x, Object[i].position.y, Object[i].position.z);
        D3DXMatrixScaling(&ScaleMat, planetscaling[i], planetscaling[i], planetscaling[i]);
        Object[i].toParentXForm = rotMat * TransMat;
    }

        D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rotMat, 5.0f);
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&TransMat, Object[0].position.x, Object[0].position.y, Object[0].position.z);
        D3DXMatrixScaling(&ScaleMat, planetscaling[0], planetscaling[0], planetscaling[0]);
        Object[0].toParentXForm = rotMat * TransMat;
        Object[0].ScaleXForm = ScaleMat * TransMat;


    DIMOUSESTATE2 mouseState;
    ZeroMemory(&mouseState, sizeof(mouseState));

    // Get the input device state
    hr = m_pDIMouse->GetDeviceState( sizeof(DIMOUSESTATE2), &mouseState );
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        hr = m_pDIMouse->Acquire();

        // Device has probably been lost if failed, if so keep trying to get it until it’s found.
        while( hr == DIERR_INPUTLOST)
        {
            hr = m_pDIMouse->Acquire();
        }

        // If we failed for some other reason
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            if(FAILED(hr))
            return;
            // Read the device state again
            m_pDIMouse->GetDeviceState(sizeof(DIMOUSESTATE2), &mouseState);
        }

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if(mouseState.rgbButtons[1] & 0x80)
        {
            planetscaling[i] += mouseState.lX * 0.01f; // X Axis
            planetscaling[i] += mouseState.lY * 0.01f; // Y Axis
            m_pD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_NORMALIZENORMALS, true);
        }
    }

            rad = 270.0f;
            radM = 150.0f;
            radV = 215.0f;
            radMA = 360.0f;
            radJ = 260.0f;
            radS = 330.0f;
            radU = 390.0f;
            radN = 450.0f;
            radMO = 370.0f;
            radMOON = 300.0f;

            double time = timeGetTime() * 0.00009;
            double timeM = timeGetTime() * 0.0002;
            double timeV = timeGetTime() * 0.0001;
            double timeMA = timeGetTime() * 0.00008;
            double timeJ =  timeGetTime() * 0.000009;
            double timeS = timeGetTime() * 0.000008;
            double timeU = timeGetTime() * 0.000007;
            double timeN = timeGetTime() * 0.000006;
            double timeMO = timeGetTime() * 0.00009;
            double timeMOON = timeGetTime() * 0.00009;

            Object[2].position.x = sin(timeM)*radM;
            Object[2].position.y = cos(timeM)*radM;

            Object[3].position.x = sin(timeV)*radV;
            Object[3].position.y = cos(timeV)*radV;

            Object[1].position.x = sin(time)*rad;
            Object[1].position.y = cos(time)*rad;

            Object[4].position.x = sin(timeMA)*radMA;
            Object[4].position.y = cos(timeMA)*radMA;

            Object[5].position.x = sin(timeJ)*radJ;
            Object[5].position.y = cos(timeJ)*radJ;

            Object[6].position.x = sin(timeS)*radS;
            Object[6].position.y = cos(timeS)*radS;

            Object[7].position.x = sin(timeU)*radU;
            Object[7].position.y = cos(timeU)*radU;

            Object[8].position.x = sin(timeN)*radN;
            Object[8].position.y = cos(timeN)*radN;

            Object[9].position.x = sin(timeMO)*radMO;
            Object[9].position.y = cos(timeMO)*radMO;

            Object[9].position.x = sin(timeMOON)*radMOON;
            Object[9].position.y = cos(timeMOON)*radMOON;




    // For each object...
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        // Initialize to identity matrix.
        D3DXMatrixIdentity(&Object[i].toWorldXForm);
        D3DXMatrixIdentity(&Object[0].ScaleForm);

        // The ith object's world transform is given by its
        // to-parent transform, followed by its parent's
        // to-parent transform, followed by its grandparent's
        // to-parent transform, and so on, up to the root's
        // to-parent transform.
        int k = i;
        while( k != -1 ) // While there exists an ancestor.
        {
            Object[i].toWorldXForm *= Object[k].toParentXForm;
            Object[i].ScaleForm *= Object[k].ScaleXForm;
            k = Object[k].parent; // Move up the ancestry chain.
            k = Object[k].parent2;
        }
    }


}
```

It actually crashes right at the end of the while loop, and when it does it opens up a new file called d3dx9math.inl, which I don't even understand, because thats not my file, but its a file associated with directx. Here is the code that it shows me when it does crash

```
D3DXMATRIX::operator FLOAT* ()
{
    return (FLOAT *) &_11;
}

D3DXINLINE
D3DXMATRIX::operator CONST FLOAT* () const
{
    return (CONST FLOAT *) &_11;
}


// assignment operators
D3DXINLINE D3DXMATRIX&
D3DXMATRIX::operator *= ( CONST D3DXMATRIX& mat )
{
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(this, this, &mat);
    return *this;
}

D3DXINLINE D3DXMATRIX&
D3DXMATRIX::operator += ( CONST D3DXMATRIX& mat )
{
    _11 += mat._11; _12 += mat._12; _13 += mat._13; _14 += mat._14;
    _21 += mat._21; _22 += mat._22; _23 += mat._23; _24 += mat._24;
    _31 += mat._31; _32 += mat._32; _33 += mat._33; _34 += mat._34;
    _41 += mat._41; _42 += mat._42; _43 += mat._43; _44 += mat._44;
    return *this;
}

D3DXINLINE D3DXMATRIX&
D3DXMATRIX::operator -= ( CONST D3DXMATRIX& mat )
{
    _11 -= mat._11; _12 -= mat._12; _13 -= mat._13; _14 -= mat._14;
    _21 -= mat._21; _22 -= mat._22; _23 -= mat._23; _24 -= mat._24;
    _31 -= mat._31; _32 -= mat._32; _33 -= mat._33; _34 -= mat._34;
    _41 -= mat._41; _42 -= mat._42; _43 -= mat._43; _44 -= mat._44;
    return *this;
}
```

it shows the arrow pointing inside this function D3DXMATRIX::operator *= ( CONST D3DXMATRIX& mat ), at the return *this line. I don't know if this exception has to do with trying to run it on a new operating system, or maybe something isn't installed on the computer, but was installed on the previous one. and this is a 3d project as well, but I also noticed that when I go inside the project folder and trying to open up one of the 3d objects, it says an error occurred tying to open that type of file, which is a .x file. Its weird to because I have directx installed on the computer. Microsoft directx sdk (June 2010) version. I don't know if its the version of directx or that I cant open up the .x file from the project folder which could be causing the project to crash like it is. So this is my issue, and any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks a lot

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: BTW, while you can run Direct3D 9 applications on Windows 8.x--likely requiring the installation of the D3DX9 helper library using the legacy DirectX SDK or DirectX End-User Runtime, debugging support for Direct3D 9 is limited on Windows 8.x. See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk.aspx) and [Not So Direct Setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx).